# Removing white space after looping a list

Tags: python

So, I've tried stripping from several of the variables, and I know their is no white space previously to the return statement, so I tried striping the variable in the `return` statement but the white space is still there...

Something easy I'm sure or maybe it would be best to re-write the loop?

```
def main():
    file = input("File name:")
    extension(file)


def extension(s):
    split = (s.split("."))
    join_s = (''.join(split[1]))
    image_e = ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png']
    for i in image_e:
        print(image_e)
        if join_s in image_e:
            return print("Image/", join_s)
        else:
            return print("Application/", join_s)


main()
```

Output looks something like this:

```
Image/ jpg
```

**Edit:** One of the comments had asked why I used `return` and it was because if I just used print it would display the print 3-4 different times, is there a reason why I shouldn't use `return` in this situation or why it exactly does display it 4 times in row? (Assuming because of the loop.)

Comment: What is the point of `return print`?  Did you try `print("Image/"+join_s)`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Well you tell me what is the point haha, I am new getting back into python, let me give it a shot... yes that did work is there a reason I shouldn't be using return? I tried without the returns and now I know why, is because if I didn't have the return in there it prints it four different times. Maybe was my way of sloppy solving a bug.

Comment: when you use `print(...  , ...)` with comma then every comma automatically add space between values. if you want without comman then you may need to use `print(..., ..., sep="")` or you have to create one string before printing. `print( "Image/"+join_s )` or `print( f"Image/{join_s}" )`

Comment: Please make sure you understand that `print` and `return` have **nothing to do with each other**, and study what each is used for.

Comment: Also, please read [ask] and try to **ask a clear question**. What is supposed to happen when you run the code? What happens instead, and how is that different? "Something easy i'm sure or maybe it would be best to re-write the loop?" is not something we can work with - it sounds like you're saying that you think the problem is easy to deal with, but it isn't clear *what the problem is*, and it isn't clear *what you want to know* about that problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I do understand that return is returns like True or False right its a Boolean, and I do understand they are different but yes I will need to do a little more studying. Thank you, and yes sorry if the question wasn't clear I apologize.

Comment: `return` exits the function, so your loop will never "loop".  It will return on the first pass.

Comment: @MarkTolonen okay, cool so that's going to be an issue as I move with this further, I will attempt to make it work with just the print function now, surely I can solve this one on my own why it's printing four times.

Comment: It would help if you explained what "extension" is supposed to do?  It looks like you want to generate a content type string.

Comment: @MarkTolonen really it's just something simple I am doing to practice, the user inputs a file name "dog.zip" it splits it off from the "." and then I just simply loop to see if it matches one of the pre-set extensions I have set in a list to tell weather its an image or an application.

Comment: As you can see from my answer, the loop isn't required, nor the `join`.  Just look for the extension `in` the list.  That's why it was printing for times...the loop is running the `if` for times do to the length of the list, but it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to generate a content type string.  This will do it:

```py
import os

def extension(s):
    ext = s.rsplit('.')[1]  # split on the *last* period
    if ext in ('jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png'):
        return f'Image/{ext}'
    else:
        return f'Application/{ext}'

file = input('File name: ')
content_type = extension(file)
print(content_type)
```

Output:

```
File name: test.jpg
Image/jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to determine the mimetype from a given filename.

```
import mimetypes

filename = "somefilename.png"
guessed_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
```

guessed_type:

> image/png

Comment: Thanks everyone for the other ways of doing this, I am currently just practicing simple things such as loops is the way I am doing it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Python has many features/functions available to you via the standard libraries.

Here are some other methods:

`os`

```
import os
​
filename = "somefilename.png"
base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

> ('somefilename', '.png')

`pathlib`

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = "somefilename.png"
f = Path(filename)
f.suffix
```

> '.png'

For strings python has `.startswith()` and `.endswith()` methods, which can optionally take an iterable, so you can write this without splitting the string:

```
filename = "somefilename.png"

image_exts = ('jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png')

if filename.endswith(image_exts):
    ext = filename.split(".")[-1]
    print(f"Image/{ext}")
```